# How to pass two data from jquery ajax to php and receive data on success using json datatype

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery Ajax coding, my below code is always failing. I am suspecting on data I have sending using json datatype is problem or the data:.... how I am concatenate is a problem.   I checked the jquery syntax validation it says fine in jsfiddle.

```
 function funCal(ID, value) {
        var IDjs = ID;
        var valuejs = value;

     $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"Valid.php",
            data: "id="+IDjs+"&value="+valuejs,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                    //output data    
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Error');
                }


            });
        }
```

Any help will be most appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Any errors in your browser's developer console? What type of values are `ID` and `value`?

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for reply ID=AB123 ID=DC213 ID=AS234 etc and value=87 value=23.35 , value=32.1 etc. No error actually. But it always fails and jumps to error. Is it because of the return data is having problem? on the php side I have received the variable using POST. calculated it and return using echo json_encode($variable);

Comment: The `error` callback does **NOT** accept a single `data` argument. I suggest you read the [documentation carefully](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) and perhaps don't throw away all that valuable information with an entirely unhelpful `alert('Error')`

Comment: Your are right, there was syntax and coding errors found had to be specific. Actually, I had to go through the send from jquery and response from php of  dataType: 'Json'.Once the syntax was correctly given everything was just automatic. Great Thanks for the for direction.

Comment: error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {                 alert('An error occured!'+( errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status)); }});